# Retornar linhas não repetidas em um Select

Tags: banco-de-dados, oracle, select

Estou usando o seguinte select no oracle

```
select DISTINCT delivery, dt_coletado from table1
```

e é retornado a seguinte linha

```
 DELIVERY      DT_COLETADO
8816619995  2019-05-17 00:51:04
8816619995  2019-05-16 20:06:56
```

quero saber uma forma de retornar apenas a linha que tem a data da coluna DT_COLETADO maior. Que no caso é a linha com a data do dia 17-05-2019.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
    delivery, max(dt_coletado)AS dt_coletado
FROM table1
GROUP BY delivery
```

Comment: Muito obrigado Silvair L. Soares. Funcionou.

Comment: É um prazer para mim poder ajudar. Boa sorte.